# Spring Boot Remote Oracle DB connection works on Windows 10 OS but not on Oracle Linux OS

Tags: linux, windows-10, spring-data, oracle10g, java-11

I am working on a spring boot project with oracle jdk 11 on an eclipse 4.21.0 IDE environment. When I create a jar package and deploy it,  the connection to the database is working without any problem. The connection to the oracle database is  done to a remote location inside our LAN.
Everything is working without any problem when I work on development and deployment mode in  Windows 10.

When I deploy as client the same spring boot jar file with  oracle jdk 11 inside of our LAN from another OS location (Ubuntu 20.04, Oracle Linux 8) all functionalities are working appart the connection to the oracleDB. The weird thing is that:

1. It does not show any error so it *seems* to be connecting but returns an empty set
2. Both deployments(from Windows 10, Linux) are done to a remote oracle DB inside our LAN
3. On the Linux OS I installed an oracle client and did an sqlplus direct connection
   in the form of  `sqlplus username/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=LAN_IP)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=db_sid)))` to the remote DB and it succeeded.

Any ideas where I should focus on to locate any error. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the Oracle DB Server to be able to see what server is receiving.